# Jquery ajax form submission and spring MVC

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring

I am testing some form submission code using spring MVC in the book "professional java for web applications". You can find the complete code in chapter 13 the spring-forms project

http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Java-for-Web-Applications.productCd-1118656466,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html

It works fine without the ajax part in the .jsp below. But when I add the jquery ajax part in the jsp, it does not work. The alert shows name to be undefined.

What did I do wrong?

Here is the code in the controller that binds the userForm object to the form in the .jsp below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "user/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String createUser(Map<String, Object> model)
{
    model.put("userForm", new UserForm());
    return "user/add";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "user/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public View createUser(@ModelAttribute("userForm") UserForm form)
{
    User user = new User();
    user.setUserId(this.getNextUserId());
    user.setUsername(form.getUsername());
    user.setName(form.getName());
    this.userDatabase.put(user.getUserId(), user);

    return new RedirectView("/user/list", true, false);
}
```

Here is the .jsp file

```
<%--@elvariable id="userForm" type="com.wrox.site.UserForm"--%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>    
        <title>${title}</title>

<script src="http:////code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#submitForm').submit(function(e) {
            var frm = $('#submitForm');
            e.preventDefault();


        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data : frm.serialize(), //JSON.stringify(data),

            success : function(callback){
                alert("Response: Name: "+callback.name);
                $(this).html("Success!");
            },
            error : function(){
                $(this).html("Error!");
            }
        });
        });
    });
</script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>${title}</h1>
        <form:form method="post"  modelAttribute="userForm" id = "submitForm">
            <form:label path="username">Username</form:label><br />
            <form:input path="username" /><br />
            <br />
            <form:label path="name">Name:</form:label><br />
            <form:input path="name" /><br />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </form:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the userForm

```
package com.wrox.site;

public class UserForm
{
    private String username;
    private String name;

    public String getUsername()
    {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username)
    {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Here is the list.jsp

```
<%--@elvariable id="userList" type="java.util.Collection<com.wrox.site.User>"--%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>User List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Users</h2>
        [<a href="<c:url value="/user/add" />">new user</a>]<br />
        <br />
        <c:forEach items="${userList}" var="user">
            ${user.name} (${user.username})
            [<a href="<c:url value="/user/edit/${user.userId}"/>">edit</a>]<br/>
        </c:forEach>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what your redirect call responds back?

Comment: No. But without using ajax, everything works fine. I assume that the ajax part is doing exactly the same as the original form submission without ajax. But i must have missed sth.

Comment: Can you please add method to which you are redirecting to? /user/list ?

Comment: added the list.jsp. you can find the complete code in chapter 13 spring-forms project here: http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Java-for-Web-Applications.productCd-1118656466,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html